# How do I check if Point3d is not null?

Tags: c#, null, nullable, autocad, autocad-plugin

My approach was...

```
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d point = null;
```

but I can't seem to set a `Point3d` to `null`.

Can anyone tell me why and how I would check whether a `Point3d` is `null`?

(By `Point3D` I mean `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d`)

Comment: Are you asking about *setting* something to `null`, or about checking wether it is `null`?

Comment: Is `Point3d` a reference type? What do you mean by _can't_? You get any error message when you try to do that? It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Also, are you asking about [`System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Point3D`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.point3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or something entirely else?

Comment: Is there a `Point3D.Empty` to compare against?

Comment: It is about AutoCAD! It has a `Point3d` struct there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Autocad `Point3d` is a `struct`. Hence it can't be null, it *always* has a value.

At most, you can test it for invalid numbers. Possibly there is a `Point3d.Empty` static property to test against.

If you want it to be able to be `null`, use `Point3d?` which makes the `struct` nullable (by wrapping it in `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: I didn't want to insinuate the OP is using the Web UI `Point3D`, just pointed out that there are many `Point3D` structures (and the one from AutoCAD might not be "well-known" enough for the question to be inherently clear). +1 for the clarification in your answer.

Comment: Is it good practice (clean code) to use 'Point3d?' and make it nullable or is it something I should avoid?

Comment: @MikeDelta: Depends on your needs. If it has to be, since it is necessary in your logic, you definitely should. I see no harm in it.

Answer (score 1):

`Point3d` is not a class but a struct so it will never be null. But you can use the fact that the default value is (0, 0, 0). So you can check whether it equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to check is to see if the point == Point3d.Origin.

Comment: Only for specific cases. Point3d.Origin still has a valid value so if you expect either a Point3d or no Point3d this is probably not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The `Point3D` is a struct, not a class.
A struct in C# cannot have a null value.
If you need to work with a type that might be a Point3D or might be null, you should use `Nullable<Point3D>` or `Point3D?`

Read this page to learn the differences between structures and classes: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Point3d` is a `struct`, it cannot be `null`. However, you *can* create a `Nullable<Point3d>` object, which *can* be `null`:

```
Point3d? point = null;
```

However, now you have to interact with it using some slightly more complicated semantics:

```
if (point.HasValue) {
    // do something with point.Value, which is a Point3d
} else {
    // handle point == null
}
```